# Can we write the Quantum Fidelity between two density operators in terms of Quasi-Probability Distributions: $P$, $Q$ and $W$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, probability, quantum-optics, density-operator

Quantum Fidelity between two density operators, $\hat{\rho}$ and $\hat{\sigma}$, is given by $F(\hat{\rho},\hat{\sigma})=\left(Tr\sqrt{\sqrt{\hat{\rho}}\hat{\sigma}\sqrt{\hat{\rho}}}\right)^2$, where $Tr$ represents the trace.

If both the density operators represent pure states: $\hat{\rho}=|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$ and $\hat{\rho}=|\phi\rangle\langle\phi|$ then this becomes $|\langle\psi|\phi\rangle|^2$.

$|\langle\psi|\phi\rangle|^2 = h\int W_{\psi}(x,p)W_{\phi}(x,p)dxdp$ in terms of the Winger functions (From Eqn. (19) in Case, W. B. (2008). Wigner functions and Weyl transforms for pedestrians. American Journal of Physics, 76(10), 937-946.)

Do we have a similar expression in terms of the Quasi-Probability Distributions: P and Q instead of the density operators when the states are pure?

Is there also a general expression for the case of mixed states?

Comment: Somewhat [related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27590/an-entropy-of-the-wigner-function/68190#68190).

Comment: [Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/264243/how-can-we-define-the-distance-for-a-pair-quantum-states-in-phase-space).